# Design Problems with Mathematical Expression Parser

Tags: java, design-patterns, tree

I am writing an expression evaluator that parses a mathematical expression and returns an abstract syntax tree. My tree consists of operator nodes, number nodes, and variables nodes. Each of these implement the ASTNode interface which requires the getValue() method to be implemented.

---

#### Operator Node

My first design problem comes with the operator node. I have an abstract operator class that contains fields for information about precedence, whether the operator is unary or binary, and whether or not the operator is right associative. These fields are set through a protected constructor. There is a single abstract method operate() that allows the client to extend the operator class and create their own operators. I also have a number of default operators which are stored in a static DEFAULT_OPERATORS HashMap. Each operator node stores an operator and operands, which are just other ASTNodes. When getValue() is called on an operator node, it gets the values of its argument nodes and then returns a result using the operation defined by its operator. Each operator must only exist once as several different operator nodes can point to the same operator, but I see no way of enforcing that the client maintain this. For instance, ever plus node in the tree should share the same instance of the plus operator.

---

#### Variable Node

This problem is a little less complicated. A variable node simply returns the value of its variable which is set by the client. I intend to store the value of the variables in a HashMap mapping the name to the value. But where does this HashMap get stored and how is it associated with the tree. Variable nodes are leafs and all variable nodes need access to the HashMap, but the values must be set from the client who only has access to the root of the tree. I need some way of making the variables HashMap globally accessible by every node in the tree and I'd rather avoid giving each node a reference to the map with the ability to set the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the operators being (or not being) singleton instances, if your operator implementations have no state, that should not really pose a problem. If they do have state, it's the client implementor's job to guarantee they don't get messed up. I'm not sure there's anything you can do on the "API" end.

As for the variable lookup problem, your `evaluate` (or `getValue`) method should take a `context` parameter, which would allow for lookup of variable values. This also allows you to have operators that set variables, as well.

Comment: I think the reason it seems weird to me is because I'm essentially trying to use extension as a form of instantiation. The operator class defines state information but instead of instantiating each operator, I extend in order to define the operators functionality. So the implementation of the operate method ends up being part of the operators state in a sense. After looking over some design patterns, I noticed its resembles the bridge pattern fairly closely, and none of the examples I've seen of the bridge pattern use singleton instances of the implementation classes so I suppose this works.

Comment: Regarding the variables, are you saying pass the HashMap down the tree as a parameter to my getValue method? This is the current way I am doing things but I don't like creating a new HashMap every time I want to retrieve a value. I need the HashMap to be part of the tree's state.

Comment: You don't create a new Map on every call, you pass the same instance down the tree.

An alternative is to use the Visitor pattern, and give the visitor access to the evaluation context (the map).